# Get Column Value dynamically and edit the column manually in Sharepoint Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I am creating a leave system.

There are fields like:

1. Type of leave as text
2. From date as date
3. To date as date and 
   there is a calculated column named 'RequestedDays' which calculates the number of leave days requested excluding weekends.

Now, I need a field in the edit form which dynamically updates to 8*'RequestedDays' as soon as requestor enters his From date and To date.

I would also like to edit this 'leave hours' field manually and then submit to my manager for approval.
How can I do this?

Comment: by the way I am using Sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

The following example code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var $fromDate=$("input[title='From date']");
    var $toDate=$("input[title='To date']");
    var $leaveHours=$("input[title='leave hours']");
    $leaveHours.val(getLeaveHours($fromDate.val(),$toDate.val()));  
    $fromDate.get(0).onvaluesetfrompicker = function(){
        $leaveHours.val(getLeaveHours($(this).val(),$toDate.val()));
    };
    $toDate.get(0).onvaluesetfrompicker = function(){
        $leaveHours.val(getLeaveHours($fromDate.val(),$(this).val()));
    };
})
function getLeaveHours(fromDate,toDate){
    var count = 0;
    var startDate = new Date(fromDate);
    var endDate = new Date(toDate);
    while (startDate <= endDate) {
        var dayOfWeek = startDate.getDay();
        if(!((dayOfWeek == 6) || (dayOfWeek == 0)))
           count++;
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return count*8;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: But how can I integrate this js code into sharepoint-online? I am unable to find any html file that can display my form layout. Do you know how to do this in power-apps?

Comment: If you use modern UI in list form, we can't add JavaScript code to achieve it. We can't use JavaScript code in PowerApps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. It can be done in Powerapps where you can customize your form. I added that 'Calculated Hours' field and was able to get result dynamically. Here are following threads that can help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bse4fBO2orE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqH1U0_TanI

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/hi-in/blog/excluding-weekends-and-holidays-in-date-differences-in-powerapps/

Note that the sharepoint formulas are not the same as Powerapps formulas